# How can I allow (or replace) ampersands using .NET's XML library?

Tags: .net, xml

Let's say that I have the following XML:

```
<someRootElement>
  <someTagWithUrl>http://www.google.com/s.php&test=testing</someTagWithUrl>
</someRootElement>
```

The ampersand inside the someTagWithUrl is invalid and needs to be escaped (by using `&amp;`), but suppose I have a single string with the entire above contents.

How can I safely escape the ampersand so it becomes valid XML?  Can .NET's XML library ignore this?  (currently XElement.Parse will throw an exception)

I've thought about using a regular expression to search for ampersands between tags but I can't quite get the syntax correct.  (something like >(\&)\< as a regex replace using & but I can't figure it out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for your regular expression:

```
&(?!quot;|apos;|amp;|lt;|gt;#x?.*?;)
```

This will find only the invalid standalone `&` characters in your text (those that aren't part of an entity).  Here's a sample of how you'd do text replacements before processing the source data as XML:

```
var regex = new Regex("&(?!quot;|apos;|amp;|lt;|gt;#x?.*?;)");
string fixedXml = regex.Replace(input, "&amp;");
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Will that only find ampersands between tags?  (eg. a relatively safe replacement?)

Comment: It shouldn't matter.  Ampersands are always invalid when they're not describing entities, and they're not allowed inside of tags either, either as element names, attribute names, or attribute values.  The only problem you could encounter is if `CDATA` sections are in your XML; if so, the solution will be much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

What you've pasted is invalid XML and any attempt to parse it with the XML libraries will fail.  The best way to ensure that it is properly escaped is to use XML/HTML writers to create the data.  For example the `XmlWriter`. They will ensure all strings are properly escaped.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm parsing already written XML so if I want to use it I need to solve this problem.  I know it's invalid XML but I still need to use it...

Comment: @SofaKing if that's the case then you're in a really tough spot.  You'll likely need to do some unsafe replacement of `&` characters with `&amp;` and do your best to avoid CData sections.  Unfortunately I don't see another way out of it because you're trying to parse non-standard XML with standard parsers.

Comment: Luckily I don't have to deal with CData so I guess it shouldn't be that bad?

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression like this would get you matching ampersands outside of tags

```
>[^<]*(&)[^<]*<
```

Comment: That looks like that would work.  Can you tell me what the .NET function call would look like to use that?  (eg.  RegEx.Replace(myString, ">[^<]*(&)[^<]*<", "&amp;") or something like that?)